# Bash loop with iterator as variable in YQ command

Tags: bash, yq

I have several files that I need to update accross several directories. Normally I would do that with a bash loop. I was trying to do the same with YQ, but with no luck.

Just to point out, since the question's been flagged as a duplicate of "Bash: difference between single and double quotes" - this is not a question about bash syntax, but yq syntax.

I was hoping this would work:

```
for i in one two three four;
do
yq -i '.key = "$i-something"' ./$i/file.yaml;
done
```

This would, however, store the literal value of what's been given, so it would be `key: $i-something`, which is not what I need. I would need it to be like `key: one-something`.

If I tried switching the quotes, like `yq -i ".key = '$i-something'" ./$i/file.yaml;` that would produce an error stating `Error: 1:12: invalid input text "'one..."`

Any ideas?

Comment: You could swap the quotes, double quotes are the _outside quotes_ and single quotes are the _inner quotes_

Comment: That gives this error:

Error: 1:12: invalid input text "'one-..."

Comment: You might want to tell which version of yq you're using. Apparently there's a wrapper version for jq and https://github.com/mikefarah/yq.

Comment: What exactly was your problem with @Kamuffel's deleted answer? Passing the value of `$i-something` via `--arg` is preferred to trying to dynamically generate a filter that contains the value.

Comment: I can't find the command in the history so I cannot reproduce and tell exactly, and I don't remember what exactly the syntax was like, something like -i --arg var that was used in substitution, but yq that I use doesn't accept that as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes in *both* places:

```
for i in one two three four; do
  yq -i ".key = \"$i-something\"" ./$i/file.yaml;
done
```

Comment: quoting mess makes me headaches..... did you try groovy with bash????  (Jenkinsfile)
that's the winner so far for creating headaches...